# Change expand menu direction

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, menustrip

I want to know there is a way to change the direction in which a menu expands.

I have a menu at the bottom of the form and I want it to expand upwards when I click my mouse over an item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you manually placed your [menustrip](/questions/tagged/menustrip) at the bottom of the form, or docked it?  In my experience, if you dock it then the menu expands upwards automatically.